# Event Handler to get rows of tables MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make an event in phpmyadmin that will get the number of rows in a number of tables and then insert the results into another database. The only issue is I can't seem to be able to use mysql to count the rows and then also put them into the table. I've also tried to set mysql variables with the COUNT(). Here is the current code that I have:

```
    INSERT INTO user_count (users,taps,statues,questions,friendships,expressions) 
    SELECT COUNT(*) from `users`,COUNT(*) from `taps`,COUNT(*) from `status`,
    COUNT(*) from `questions`,COUNT(*) from `friends`,COUNT(*) from `expressions`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Following query would be worked for you.

```
INSERT INTO user_count (users, taps, statues, questions, friendships, expressions) 
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from `users`)
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from `taps`)
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from `statues`)
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from `questions`)
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from `friendships`)
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from `expressions`)
;
```